# How to write backslash into yaml

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, yaml

I'am trying to rewrite zend framework configuration file from application.ini to application.yml format and I have some unsolvable problem for me.

in application.ini i have this:

```
pluginPaths.Bisna\Application\Resource\ = "Bisna/Application/Resource"
```

and it works. But if I try it write to yaml file I get an error about unsupported syntax

```
pluginPaths:
  Bisna\Application\Resource\: Bisna/Application/Resource
```

I tried so much ways to solve this, but no worked..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Zend_Config_Yaml` doesn't support the backslash in the key names. The relevant line in the source code is the following:

> preg_match("/(\w+):\s*(.*)/", $line, $m)

([Zend/Config/Yaml.php](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend%20Framework&path=/tags/release-1.11.11/library/Zend/Config/Yaml.php), line 313 in ZF 1.11.11). It's matching only `[A-Za-z0-9_]` for the YAML key names.

The parsing method is different from `Zend_Config_Ini`, which uses a call to the `parse_ini_file()` PHP function. That's why it was working with .ini files.

So, I don't think there is any easy solution, unless you want to modify the ZF source code (which I don't recommend).

Hope that helps,